# how to make the rust list do not removed after run iterator

Tags: list, rust

I passed a vec parameter into function in rust like this:

```
pub fn songs(playlist_records: Vec<QueryFavorites>) -> Vec<MusicResponse> {
}
```

first step I get the ids from `playlist_records` to execute a query, this is the code:

```
let ids: Vec<String> = playlist_records
        .into_iter()
        .map(|item| item.source_id.to_string())
        .collect();
```

when I use the `playlist_records` second time to fetch the field after get the query result:

```
for query_song in &results {
   let favTime: Vec<QueryFavorites> = playlist_records
       .into_iter()
       .filter(|item| item.source_id == query_song.source_id)
       .collect();
}
```

it tell me the `playlist_records` was moved. This is the message:

```
`playlist_records` moved due to this method call, in previous iteration of loop
```

I tried to borrow the `playlist_records` like this:

```
let ids: Vec<String> = &playlist_records
        .into_iter()
        .map(|item| item.source_id.to_string())
        .collect();
```

seems did not work, what should I do to reuse the `playlist_records`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change `into_iter` to use `iter`, since `into_iter` consumes the collection while `iter` iterates by reference and doesn't consume, see more about [the difference here](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/index.html):

[playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=e69e356e4e542fe3453c3b633a25f3f0)

```
let ids: Vec<String> = playlist_records
    .iter()
    .map(|item| item.source_id.to_string())
    .collect();

let favTime: Vec<&QueryFavorites> = playlist_records
  .iter()
  .filter(|item| item.source_id == "someid")
  .collect();
```

which however means your `favTime` will be of `Vec<&QueryFavorites>` type if that's fine with you. Otherwise, you can always clone the iterator.

```
let favTime: Vec<QueryFavorites> = playlist_records
  .iter()
  .cloned()
  .filter(|item| item.source_id == "someid")
  .collect();
```

[playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=2a7e734bf727f757eaa4762785f6f84e)